# Difference between Image URI behaviour in code and in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have an Image declared in some XAML as:

```
<Image Width="188" Height="56" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="..\Images\myImage.png" />
```

This is a static image and does not need to change during program execution.

I also have an image which does need to change at runtime, depending on a set of values.

I am using an iValueConverter to convert the data to images, which seems to work, but I am having trouble creating the images themselves.

I am attempting to create a series of `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` objects to store the images. As in the code above, I am trying to access a .PNG stored in the \Images directory:

```
Dim ThisImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("..\Images\thisImage.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

Whereas using `"..\Images\" appears to work fine for the XAML, correctly opening the image stored in [Project Directory]\Images\, in code it seems to direct to [Project Directory]\bin\Images\, which doesn't exist.

I'm obviously screwing up something, here, but I don't want to start trying to navigate directly to the file, as it obviously won't be in the same location once it's installed...

What am I missing, here? Why is the XAML URI not working the same as the code URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define the `Image.Source` property in XAML with a URI, a converter (`ImageSourceConverter`) is used to convert that URI to an `ImageSource` instance. The converter has access to the `IUriContext` of the XAML element, so it knows the base URI to use to resolve the relative URI.

When you create a `BitmapImage` in code, the `BitmapImage` class doesn't have access to the URI context, so it doesn't know how to resolve the relative URI. You need to specify an absolute URI, with the form `"pack://application:,,,/Images/thisImage.png"`

Comment: Thanks. I've has a nice read-through of the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) page. Most useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue is that you're using a relative Uri when, in this context, you'll have to provide an absolute one.

It works as you are expecting in XAML because, within the ImageSourceConverter (which is used to convert a Uri in xaml into an ImageSource), relative Uris are converted to absolute Uris by using the [IUriContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iuricontext.aspx) service which is available via the [ITypeDescriptorContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext.aspx).  In other words, the Uri isn't magic.  There is lots of heavy work being done (in this case, by the xaml deserializer) in order to transform a relative Uri in xaml into an ImageSource.